# How do i use conditional statement to check the value of a constructed function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, constructor, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a form bot using Javascript and I want to check the value of the function I constructed outside of a different function using conditional statements. I constructed this function using a construct such as:

### First Constructor:

this constructor creates the checkboxes.

```
class Checkbox {
  constructor(label, text) {
  // create the necessary elements
  this.label = document.createElement(label);
  this.description = document.createTextNode(text);
  this.checkbox = document.createElement("input");

  this.checkbox.type = "checkbox"; // make the element a checkbox
  this.checkbox.name = "slct[]"; // give it a name we can check on the server side
  this.checkbox.value = text; // make its value "pair"

  this.label.appendChild(this.checkbox); // add the box to the element
  this.label.appendChild(this.description); // add the description to the element

  // add the label element to your div
  document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(this.label);
}
};
```

## Second Constructor

this creates the text that is populated in the form.

then I created my checkbox that I want my form to bot.

```
var options = {};
function feelingCheckboxs() {
  option.happy = new FeelingCheckbox(feeling, "happiness");
  option.Sad = new feelingCheckbox(feeling, "Sad");
  option.angry = feelingCheckbox(feeling, "angry");
}
```

## This is the Bot that I created

```
bot() {
 if (counter == 2) {
       if (option.happy.checked = true 
            && option.sad.checked = true 
            && option.angry.checked = true ) {
      alert(
        "I am " + feelingCheckboxs(happy) + "and" + feelingCheckboxs(sad) + "and" + feelingCheckboxs(angry) + "!"
      );
```

## Question

how can I make the conditional statement check to make sure that the checkbox is checked so it can print the statement happy

Comment: `feelingCheckbox` is not defined. if it were a subclass of `Checkbox`, you could just get the instance’s `checkbox` property’s `checked` value.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok I updated how I called the subclass. But it didn't work

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you look over the updated code?

Comment: You are using the assignment operator instead of the equality operator in your if statements e.g. you should write if (option.happy.checked)

Comment: would it actually be option.happy.checked=true? @Woody

Comment: No - option.happy.checked=true assigns the value true to the checked property, what you want to do is test whether the value is set you use === in JavaScript to do that.  You could write if (option.happy.checked === true) but you don't need to do that.

Comment: why don't I need to do that?

Comment: You really need to be consistent. If your subclass is named `FeelingCheckbox` use that in all three lines of code. If you're going to use lower case for property names, use lower case for all property names (not upper case for `Sad`).  `if` conditions must evaluate to a Boolean value. Since `option.happy.checked` returns a Boolean value, there is no need to check it against `true` or `false`; it is already checked as part of being part of a condition.